# Where do I see the user distribution for Windows 10 SDK versions so that I can choose which min version my UWP app should target?

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, windows-10

In Android, Google provides [this](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). So is there something like this for Windows 10 whether officially from Microsoft or not?

If none, then on what basis should we choose the min version to target?

Comment: Basically nobody outside of a few strange Enterprise cases are running ``10.0.10240`` (RTM), so Visual Studio today when creating a new project will default to a minimum of ``10.0.10586`` (Nov15). For a game, I'd recommend going with ``10.0.14393`` (Anniversary Update; Jul16) as your minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft unfortunately doesn't provide such distribution statistics directly, also because the OS version fragmentation is much less prominent than on Android. If we forget about the phone world, all Windows 10 PCs are egligible for all released updates, in contrast to Android where the manufacturer decides which updates will be available.

Best Windows 10 market share statistics come [from AdDuplex](http://reports.adduplex.com/reports/2018-01/). You can see the latest release of Windows 10 is already on almost 75 percent of devices and growing.

Because updates are mandatory, the market share of newest versions is always growing quite quickly. Those devices that are not updated are usually very seldom used or their users actively prevent update. In both cases they very likely will not actively download UWP apps from the Microsoft Store.